# Speech.Recognition Dictation of numbers only C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I am attempting to make it so a user can say `Modify X`, followed by a number, and then have my software do something according to what the number is.

Currently, `Modify X` is listened out for; though I have no idea how to then detect the number said after the command.

I found that `DictationGrammar` has a `SetDictationContext()` method. However I don't want it to detect any words, only numbers.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably start with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361633 and read about Grammars. You only use a dictation grammar when you want to recognize any possible words a user might say (think of a dictation grammar as being the complete dictionary). If you have a constrained set of words you want to recognize, use a task specific grammar. This can be created using a GrammarBuilder or similar methods.

There is a very good article that was published a few years ago at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx. It is probably the best introductory article I’ve found so far. It is a little out of date, but very helfpul. (The AppendResultKeyValue method was dropped after the beta.)

Comment: I know how to create custom grammars, i just don't really want to have to create a grammar for
Modify X (from -1000 to 1000), Modify Y (from -1000 to 1000), Modify Z (from -1000 to 1000), etc. I am reading the links though, thanks :)

Comment: Ahhh semantics are exactly what i was after. Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int minNumber = 0;
int maxNumber = 100;
Choices numbers = new Choices ();
for (int i = minNumber; i < maxNumber; i++)
{
    numbers.add(i.toString);
}
Choices myCommands = new Choices ("count");
Choices myOperators = new Choices ("plus","minus","add","subtract","multiply","times","divide");
GrammarBuilder mathGrammar = new GrammarBuilder ();
mathGrammar.add (myCommands);
mathGrammar.add (numbers);
mathGrammar.add (myOperators);
```

... load grammar and create an event.